# Why is this Perl 6 feed operator a "bogus statement"?

Tags: whitespace, raku, feed-operator

I took this example from [Day 10 – Feed operators of the Perl 6 2010 Advent Calendar](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/day-10-feed-operators/) with the slight change of `.uc` for the `.ucfirst` that's no longer there:

```
my @rakudo-people = <scott patrick carl moritz jonathan jerry stephen>;
@rakudo-people
    ==> grep { /at/ } ==> map { .uc } ==> my @who-it's-at;
say ~@who-it's-at;
```

I write it slightly differently with some additional whitespace:

```
my @rakudo-people = <scott patrick carl moritz jonathan jerry stephen>;
@rakudo-people
    ==> grep { /at/ }
    ==> map { .uc } ==> my @who-it's-at;
say ~@who-it's-at;
```

Now it's a "bogus statement":

> ```
> ===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ...
> Bogus statement
> ------>         ==> grep { /at/ }⏏<EOL>
> expecting any of:
>     postfix
>     prefix
>     statement end
>     term
> ```

This isn't a problem with just this example. Some examples in the current docs can exhibit the same behavior.

If I add an [unspace](https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Unspace) to the end of the offending line, it works again:

```
my @rakudo-people = <scott patrick carl moritz jonathan jerry stephen>;
@rakudo-people
    ==> grep { /at/ } \
    ==> map { .uc } ==> my @who-it's-at;
say ~@who-it's-at;
```

Curiously, a comment at the end of that line does not work. I would have thought it would have eaten the offending whitespace.

The [feed operator](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_==>) says:

> In the case of routines/methods that take a single argument or where the first argument is a block, it's often required that you call with parentheses

That works:

```
my @rakudo-people = <scott patrick carl moritz jonathan jerry stephen>;
@rakudo-people
    ==> grep( { /at/ } )
    ==> map { .uc } ==> my @who-it's-at;
say ~@who-it's-at;
```

But why wasn't that a problem in the first form? What is the whitespace doing here? And what situations are included in "often required"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Perl 6 documentation on [Separating Statements](http://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Separating_Statements):

> A closing curly brace followed by a newline character implies a statement separator

In other words, whenever the **closing brace of a block** is the last thing in a line (not counting whitespace and comments), then the parser implicitly inserts a semicolon after it.

This allows us to write things like the following without a semicolon after the `}`:

```perl6
my @foo = @bar.map: {
    ...
}
```

The semicolon would be ugly there, and if you had first written the loop as `for @bar { ... }` and then decided to turn it into a `map` with assignment like this, adding the trailing semicolon would be annoying and easy to forget. So for the most part, this automatic statement termination after end-of-line blocks is helpful.

However, feed operators feeding into blocks are one case (possibly the only one) where it trips people up.

To prevent it from happening, insert `\` (a.k.a. [unspace](https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Unspace)) after the block, as you've already noted. The unspace makes the whitespace which includes the newline invisible to the parser, and thus the aforementioned newline-based parser rule won't be applied.

Comment: Duh, I once knew that about the closing curly. Thanks!

Comment: I've later noted that the docs are misleading here. Only some closing braces will follow this. It depends on the state of the Perl 6 parser. It's not a good rule.